# ARCore in "orientation-only" mode

Tags: arkit, arcore

I am working in water environment where there is no possibility to use tracking proprerly.

In ARKit I could set *AROrientationTrackingConfiguration* instead of *ARWorldTrackingConfiguration* to switch to 3DOF and use sensors + GPS for translation purposes.

Is there a possibility to do the same in ARCore?

Answer (score 0):

ARCore 1.40 still does not have a 3DOF mode like its predecessor Google Tango used to have. However, you can set the XR Pose script attached to the AR Camera to [rotation only](https://forum.unity.com/threads/help-about-arfoundation-3dof.548815/).